# FILTER has mismatched range size in Google Sheets

Tags: filter, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have the following working an existing sheet2 when filtering data from sheet source A:

```
=filter({{Source!A1:F115},{Source!R1:R115},{Processed!T1:T115}},Source!Q1:Q115=w2)
```

But when a new row was entered in source A, it breaks with error:

> filter has mismatched range size. Expected row count 1, column count 1. Actual row count 116, column count 1.

When I check the formula became

```
=filter({{Source!A1:F116},{Source!R1:R116},{Processed!T1:T116}},Source!Q1:Q115=w2)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

try to not include the end row:

```
=FILTER({{Source!A1:F}, {Source!R1:R}, {Processed!T1:T}}, Source!Q1:Q=W2)
```

if that's not the option you can try to freeze it:

```
=FILTER({{INDIRECT("Source!A1:F115")}, {INDIRECT("Source!R1:R115")}, 
         {INDIRECT("Processed!T1:T115")}}, Source!Q1:Q115=W2)
```

or you can try something crazy like:

```
=FILTER({{Source!A1:F115}, {Source!R1:R115}, {Processed!T1:T115}}, 
 INDIRECT("Source!Q1:Q"&COUNTA(Source!R1:R))=W2)
```

Comment: Thank you @player0 for your response. I have tried your suggestions. Option 1 and 3 didn't work. I have used options 2 right now. Will see what happens when new response comes in.